# Server Fault cookie/login issue?

Tags: support, login

I'm a member of not only Stack Overflow but several other communities here.  While on Stack Overflow, I see that I'm a member of Server Fault and have 111 rep there; upon clicking to go there, though, I'm not recognized and advised to log in.  Haven't yet done much debugging on this.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: Cookie "acct" doesn't seem to exist there, as it does on SO, Music: Theory/Practice, etc.

Comment: Pretty sure you still have to log into every site separately. There was talk about unifying this years ago, but I haven't seen any evidence it has happened yet.

Comment: I never log in at SO or any subdomain of stackexchange.com.  I may not have visited ServerFault recently enough (and it is a different domain), so my results may not be unexpected.  Does seem weird though.

Comment: Well, what I said wasn't entirely accurate. [They did introduce a unified log-in for the *.stackexchange.com sites a while back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login), but it doesn't apply to stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, and serverfault.com, presumably because they are hosted on different domains.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I see this is anticipated and "normal" behavior, however much it violates POLA.  ;-) I'll close the thread.

Comment: Cody, would it be of any benefit to leave this question, perhaps with you adding an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you logged in in the past year and a half or so, you should've been set up with a session on Server Fault as well... unless you did so when we had a bug that mistakenly expired unused sessions on SLDs you don't normally visit or you use a browser with third-party cookies disabled/unsupported. Or cookies get cleared. Or, or, or...

It's safe for you to log in on Server Fault and your session there should get linked up to your Stack Overflow one, so if you log out later, both will be invalidated.

Comment: Thanks, Adam.  I'm not sure how long it's been since I was on ServerFault (and cared whether I was logged in) before yesterday.

Everything looks OK now.

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey Excellent, glad to hear it.

Comment: If thirdparty cookies are disabled in browser, we cannot login into serverfault (even with correct username and password), only option has been have to reset password every time on serverfault. Either make a separate db or merge them, don't use thirdparty cookies.

Comment: @mosh If you're logging in *on* Server Fault (that is, through serverfault.com/users/login), third party cookies aren't an issue. It's first-party at that point. If you can't log in, something else must be going on.

Comment: @AdamLear You are right, chrome had different passwords saved for stackoverflow and serverfault, and updating one would invalidate the other. The thirdpaarty cookies might be a red herring, but chrome shows a red checkmark saying cookies to stackoverflow blocked (when logging in to server fault). thanks.

Comment: @mosh What happens is that when you log in on SF, we go through the same flow as we do on other domains we own - we fire off requests to stack overflow, stack exchange, etc in an attempt to log you in there too via third-party cookies. It fails if you have them disabled, of course, but it doesn't affect your ability to log in on the domain you're actually on. :)

Comment: @adam, it works, now I have to use the same password (you should mention this on login failure). Third party cookies are very dangerous from privacy point of view and should never be allowed legally.